# Google-Sheet Not updating with external sheet when opened by user

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have a rather basic Google-sheet that uses importrange functions to pull data from other Google-sheets. There are other team members that open and utilize the Google-sheets with varying permissions. Every now and then I'll get a call from a user to say the sheet is not working, as soon as I (the owner of the sheet) opens the sheet, all importranges fire up and pull the data and the sheet then works perfectly. This only happens once every 2 or 3 months. Is there a way for me to ensure that the importrange functions fire every time or some function/script I can have the user trigger to refresh the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Question

Is there a way for me to ensure that the importrange functions fire every time or some function/script I can have the user trigger to refresh the data.

### Answer

You can use [Executions](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/executions), it will show you this table, you can check if everything is ok

[image]

To get there go to Apps Script > View > Executions